# SSIS - error in ExecuteSql task

Tags: ssis-2012

In SSIS, I am running a stored procedure in an ExecuteSQL Task. It is erroring out with:

> Executing the query "EXEC [dbo].[mySP]" failed with the following error: "The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I don't have any parameters or resultset.

Comment: The problem is fixed now.

I didnt focus on the other error which was being displayed. It said: unable to enlist transaction.

Comment: Fix: Changed the transaction level to Required at package level and Supported for inner containers. And Made MaxConcurrentExecutables =1, this a property at package level.

Explanation in link: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2008/unable-to-enlist-in-the-transaction/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674364/intermittent-failure-to-enlist-ssis-package-in-dtc-transaction

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error.  I had a Master Package that was executing multiple individual packages.  I thought it was a permissions issue of some sort at first because those 2 packages were the only ones touching a different schema.  Wrong.  Turns out those 2 packages were the only ones in the entire Master Package that weren't serial in nature (were running concurrently).  After I made one package run and complete before the other everything started working.